# react native pormise.all with deviceinfo and geolocation

Tags: react-native, promise

I am building my first react native application and I am using DeviceInfo (react-native-device-info) and geolocation API.

```
DeviceInfo.getMACAddress(mac => console.log(mac);
```

and

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => console.log(position)
```

both of them are returning promise. How to merge them with something like `promise.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I studied your code but what you're doing isn't called a promise, you're objectively giving a callback to the function instead of using `.then` to resolve the promise.

Check the API of GetMacAddress [here](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#getmacaddress) also the getCurrentPosition doesn't use promises, it uses callbacks instead, it's [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) is here.

What you can do to use `Promise.all` is that, you can wrap `getCurrentPosition` to a promise and then use `promise.all` with the DeviceInfo.

wrap `getposition` to a promise:

```
const getPosition = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
  });
}
```

now use `Promise.all` like this:

```
const getData = async () => {
        const [macAddress, currentPos] = await Promise.all([
            DeviceInfo.getMACAddress(),
            getPosition(),
        ]);

        // use macAddress and currentPosition here.
}
```

Now the `macAddress` and `currentPos` are the outputs of the `getMACAddress` and `getCurrentPosition` function.

If you're not using an async function, then you can do the following:

```
Promise.all([
    DeviceInfo.getMACAddress(),
    getPosition(),
]).then((macAddress, pos) => {
    // access macAddress and pos in this func
}).catch((error) => {
    // access any error here
})
```

Comment: What are reject and resolve here? Are they functions to be defined?

Comment: no these are given by every promise. When a promise is done doing its thing, it resolves. if it has an error, it rejects.